# google maps marker title does not show up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a map where there are five markers which on click open five infowindows. Everything works fine but the markers title. As a matter of fact whenever I use Firefox they just are invisible, when instead I use Chrome of Opera they are visible.

Here is the html part where I use google maps api V3 to make the map visible

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <title>Accessibilita</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&amp;key=AIzaSyD3Xz7-z7U_XzZiaOlx9khhtFSld8vd0k4"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <script src="js/maps.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
    </head>  
    <body onload="initialize('center0')">
        <div id="center0" class="ccenter0">
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

in the below js code, the first function makes the map visible and calls the caricaArray function, the second function adds the markers on the map and the third  function loads the array containing the infowindows and markers properties, at the very end of the last function a for loop loops the function which adds the makers on the map. At the beginning of the code I create an object whose properties are recalled

```js
function myObj()
{
this.id = 0;
this.score = 0;
this.title = "";
this.latitude = 0;
this.longitude = 0;
this.content = "";
this.icon = "";
this.mymarker;
this.myinfowin;
//this.latlon = 0;
this.getlatlng = function() {
        return new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);
    };
return this;
}

//blocco dichiarazioni variabili
var myitems = new Array();
var mlat = 0;
var mlon = 0;
var mnum = 0;


//var myinfowin = [];
//var mymarker = [];

var map;
//inizializzo la mappa
function initialize(x) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.882944, 12.568310);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(x), mapOptions);
 caricaArray(); 
}

//aggiungo i marker e la infowindow dentro la funzione
function addMarker(a){
   myitems[a].mymarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myitems[a].getlatlng(),
    map: map,
    title: myitems[a].title,
    icon: myitems[a].icon,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
   });
   myitems[a].myinfowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: myitems[a].content});
               google.maps.event.addListener(myitems[a].mymarker, 'click', function() {
                   myitems[a].myinfowin.open(map,this);
            });
}

//dentro la funzione searcaddress richiamo la funzione addmarker
/*function searchAddress(){
 for(var i = 0; i < myitems.length; i++) {
  myitems[i].
 }
}
*/
function caricaArray(){
    var i = 0;
     myitems[i] = new myObj();
   //myitems[i].id = parseInt(a[p]);
  // myitems[i].score = parseFloat(a[p+1]);
  myitems[i].title = "Paolo";
  myitems[i].latitude = parseFloat(41.882944);
  myitems[i].longitude = parseFloat(12.568310);
  //myitems[i].content = a[p+5] + "<br/>" + a[p+6];
  myitems[i].content = "ciao da paolo e riccardo";
  myitems[i].icon = 'img/blue-dot.png';
  //p = p + l;
  if (myitems[i].latitude > 0){
  if (myitems[i].longitude > 0){
    mlat=mlat+myitems[i].latitude;
    mlon=mlon+myitems[i].longitude
       mnum=mnum+1
   }
  }
  i = i+ 1;
  myitems[i] = new myObj();
  //myitems[i].id = parseInt(a[p]);
  // myitems[i].score = parseFloat(a[p+1]);
  myitems[i].title = "Galasso";
  myitems[i].latitude = parseFloat(41.882885);
  myitems[i].longitude = parseFloat(12.568805);
  //myitems[i].content = a[p+5] + "<br/>" + a[p+6];
  myitems[i].content = "ciao da Galasso";
  myitems[i].icon = 'img/red-dot.png';
   //p = p + l;
  if (myitems[i].latitude > 0){
  if (myitems[i].longitude > 0){
    mlat=mlat+myitems[i].latitude;
    mlon=mlon+myitems[i].longitude
   mnum=mnum+2
   }
  }
   i = i + 1;
   myitems[i] = new myObj();
   //myitems[i].id = parseInt(a[p]);
  // myitems[i].score = parseFloat(a[p+1]);
   myitems[i].title = "Riccardo";
   myitems[i].latitude = parseFloat(41.882286);
   myitems[i].longitude = parseFloat(12.559539);
   //myitems[i].content = a[p+5] + "<br/>" + a[p+6];
   myitems[i].content = "ciao da Riccardo";
   myitems[i].icon = 'img/purple-dot.png';
   //p = p + l;
   if (myitems[i].latitude > 0){
  if (myitems[i].longitude > 0){
    mlat=mlat+myitems[i].latitude;
    mlon=mlon+myitems[i].longitude
   mnum=mnum+1
   }
   }
   
   /*if ( mnum > 0){
    mlat=mlat/mnum;
        mlon=mlon/mnum;
 var mzoom = 16;
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(mlat,mlon), mzoom);
   }
  */
 for (i=0;i<myitems.length;i++){
      if (myitems[i].latitude > 0){
         addMarker(i);
    }
    }
}
console.log(title);
```

console.log returns that `title` is not defined on any browser I use, while only on Firefox the `title` does not work

Comment: Can you provide a link to a map that demonstrates the issue? If the map is not on a live web server, use a service such as JSFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=O8t0Pg4V0n here is the link as a matter of fact it is on a live web server sorry for the mistake and here is the link http://89.97.214.162/accessibilita/

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth did you find anything?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior in all browsers. I also see that you aren't doing anything with the object `title` property. You have to manually code the HTML for an infowindow title. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: The linked page shows the title on mouseover for me (with both Firefox and Chrome).  Don't see anything undefined in the console log.

Comment: @geocodezip for me to make it work I had to add optimized set to false so that the title shows on Firefox too

Comment: Perhaps you could add an answer to the question and accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in order to make my code work I had to add the property `optimized`
>   type boolean set to false. This way the markers show the title no
>   matter the browser

here is the javascript working code :

```js
function myObj()
{
this.id = 0;
this.score = 0;
this.title = "";
this.latitude = 0;
this.longitude = 0;
this.content = "";
this.icon = "";
this.mymarker;
this.myinfowin;
//this.latlon = 0;
this.getlatlng = function() {
        return new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);
    };
return this;
}

//blocco dichiarazioni variabili
var myitems = new Array();
var mlat = 0;
var mlon = 0;
var mnum = 0;


//var myinfowin = [];
//var mymarker = [];

var map;
//inizializzo la mappa
function initialize(x) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.882944, 12.568310);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(x), mapOptions);
 caricaArray(); 
}

//aggiungo i marker e la infowindow dentro la funzione
function addMarker(a){
   myitems[a].mymarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myitems[a].getlatlng(),
    map: map,
    title: myitems[a].title,
    icon: myitems[a].icon,
    optimized: false, // every marker is a separate DOM element
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
   });
   myitems[a].myinfowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: myitems[a].content});
               google.maps.event.addListener(myitems[a].mymarker, 'click', function() {
                   myitems[a].myinfowin.open(map,this);
            });
}

//dentro la funzione searcaddress richiamo la funzione addmarker
/*function searchAddress(){
 for(var i = 0; i < myitems.length; i++) {
  myitems[i].
 }
}
*/
function caricaArray(){
    var i = 0;
     myitems[i] = new myObj();
   //myitems[i].id = parseInt(a[p]);
  // myitems[i].score = parseFloat(a[p+1]);
  myitems[i].title = "xx1";
  myitems[i].latitude = parseFloat(41.882944);
  myitems[i].longitude = parseFloat(12.568310); 
  //myitems[i].content = a[p+5] + "<br/>" + a[p+6];
  myitems[i].content = "ciao da paolo e riccardo";
  myitems[i].icon = 'img/blue-dot.png';
  //p = p + l;
  if (myitems[i].latitude > 0){
  if (myitems[i].longitude > 0){
    mlat=mlat+myitems[i].latitude;
    mlon=mlon+myitems[i].longitude
       mnum=mnum+1
   }
  }
  i = i+ 1;
  myitems[i] = new myObj();
  //myitems[i].id = parseInt(a[p]);
  // myitems[i].score = parseFloat(a[p+1]);
  myitems[i].title = "xx2";
  myitems[i].latitude = parseFloat(41.882885);
  myitems[i].longitude = parseFloat(12.568805);
  //myitems[i].content = a[p+5] + "<br/>" + a[p+6];
  myitems[i].content = "ciao da Galasso";
  myitems[i].icon = 'img/red-dot.png';
   //p = p + l;
  if (myitems[i].latitude > 0){
  if (myitems[i].longitude > 0){
    mlat=mlat+myitems[i].latitude;
    mlon=mlon+myitems[i].longitude
   mnum=mnum+1
   }
  }
   i = i + 1;
   myitems[i] = new myObj();
   //myitems[i].id = parseInt(a[p]);
  // myitems[i].score = parseFloat(a[p+1]);
   myitems[i].title = "zz2";
   myitems[i].latitude = parseFloat(41.882286);
   myitems[i].longitude = parseFloat(12.559539);
   //myitems[i].content = a[p+5] + "<br/>" + a[p+6];
   myitems[i].content = "ciao da Riccardo";
   myitems[i].icon = 'img/purple-dot.png';
   //p = p + l;
   if (myitems[i].latitude > 0){
  if (myitems[i].longitude > 0){
    mlat=mlat+myitems[i].latitude;
    mlon=mlon+myitems[i].longitude
   mnum=mnum+1
   }
   }
   
   /*if ( mnum > 0){
    mlat=mlat/mnum;
        mlon=mlon/mnum;
 var mzoom = 16;
 map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(mlat,mlon), mzoom);
   }
  */
 for (i=0;i<myitems.length;i++){
      if (myitems[i].latitude > 0){
         addMarker(i);
    }
    }
}
```